# Find a formula that defines the union A ∪ B in terms of the operations of intersection and complement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The formula A\B = A∩B' defines the difference operation in terms of the operations of intersection and complement.
Find a formula that defines the union A ∪ B in terms of the operations of intersection and complement.
I have an idea for what the expression will be but if I just wrote it out and then proved it, would that be valid?

Comment: Hint: find the complement of $A\cup B$

Comment: Use De Morgan...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about
$$A \cup B = (A^c \cap B^c)^c \quad ?$$